# Regex to validate only US and India retail number

Tags: regex

I am trying to get a regex which serves below requirements:

1. Validates US, India retail phone number
2. Excludes special purpose/business purpose phone numbers in both countries. I.e. starting with 800, 888, 877, and 866, 900, at least 10 digits for US, there can be more guidelines but above is just for example.
3. It should validate special chars if any like `(`, `)`, `+`, `1`, `0` if included but satisfies all this points than should be a valid phone number.
4. If preceded by STD, ISD consider it as valid.
5. Landline, mobile both should be valid.

I looked whether some came across the same requirements, but the solutions I am getting serve different requirements and not exactly the one I am looking for.

Comment: Could you provide inputs that should match / should not match, as well as what you already tried?

Comment: We can help with the IT side, but you should be clear about what constitutes a valid phone number within your desired range.

Comment: I understand but Requirement is not to limit based on example. It's to validate all Phone nos with above characteristics but to avoid Business or special purpose phone nos like I explain in step2. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the full exclusion list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a definitive exclusion/inclusion list of the phone numbers you want to match, here is a "template" regular expression that you could use to match US numbers:

```
(?:^|\b)(\+?1[ -.\/]?)?\(?(?!37|950|958|959|96|976)[2-9]([0-8])(?!\2)\d(?:\) ?|[ -.\/])?[2-9](?!11)\d\d[ -.]?\d{4}(?:$|\b)
```

A break-down:

- `(?:^|\b)`: Start of string or break. This prevents, for example, the match of digits to start in the middle of a longer series of digits;
- `(\+?1[ -.\/]?)?`: this matches an optional prefix of the US country code (i.e. 1), and accepts values like `+1`, `1/`, `+1`, `1`;
- `\(?`: an optional opening bracket for the region code;
- `(?!37|950|958|959|96|976)`: exclusion list of region codes. When only 2 digits are given, any region code starting with those is rejected -- **you'll need to extend this list to identify other "special business" phone numbers you want to exclude**;
- `[2-9]`: first digit of region code; cannot be 0 or 1;
- `([0-8])`: second digit of region code; cannot be 9;
- `(?!\2)\d`: third digit of region code; cannot be the same as the second digit (`\2` refers to the second match group);
- `(?:\) ?|[ -.\/])?`: optional separator: `)`,`-`,`.`,`/`, or space. If `)`, it can optionally be followed by a space;
- `[2-9]`: first digit of exchange code; cannot be 0 or 1;
- `(?!11)`: exclusion for second and third digits of exchange code -- they cannot both be 1 at the same time;
- `\d\d`: second and third digit of exchange code; no further limitations;
- `[ -.]?`: optional separator; can be `-`, `.` or space;
- `\d{4}`: four digit customer number; no restrictions.
- `(?:$|\b)`: End of string or break. This prevents, for example, the match of digits to stop in the middle of a longer series of digits;

Here is an [online regex test](https://regex101.com/r/fQ9xF7/1).

I suppose with the above as inspiration, you could fine-tune it to your expectations, and add the Indian formats in the same manner. You can use the `|` operator to separate the two sub-regular expressions you will have, like `(US|IND)`, where you need to replace those two arguments by real expressions of course.

To capture also the prefix `STD` or `ISD`, you can insert the following in the above regex, right after the break test:

```
(?:STD\b\s*|ISD\b\s*|)
```

...which matches these optional words followed by optional spaces.

However, the complexity of the final regex will increase the more precise you want to match and exclude invalid numbers. For example, if you would want to validate against the [All India STD Code List](http://www.simbazar.com/Downloadfile.aspx), then your regular expression would get very long and hard to manage.

Comment: Thank.This is what I am looking for. I understand that I may have to tweak customize as per my requirements from here on. Thanks.